# What permissions are required to bulk insert in SQL Server from a network share with Windows authentication?

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-7, bulkinsert

I am working on an application which bulk-loads data into a SQL Server 2008 database. It writes a CSV file to a network share then calls a stored procedure which contains a BULK INSERT command.

I'm migrating the application to what amounts to a completely new network. In this new world bulk insertion fails with this error:

```
Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot bulk load because the file "\\myserver\share\subfolder\filename" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105).
```

I connect to the database using Windows Authentication, using the same account which wrote the file. The file, and the folder in which it resides, grant read and modify rights both to my user account and the database server's domain service account. That service account apparently has constrained delegation permitted, which is mentioned on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx). Still no good. If I connect using a SQL Server account then bulk insertion succeeds, but we are trying to stick exclusively to Windows Authentication.

Does anybody have a handle on what needs to be done to make this work? How exactly does SQL Server go about accessing data on network shares, hopping between its service account and that of the connected user? I know that I can bulk insert in a similar situation in our current infrastructure, but it is so crufty with age that it would be hard to track down what has been done to enable this in the past.

Answer (score 6):

Recently we had this issue for a number of our Devs.  I've come up with a number of ways to allow testing of bulk inserts.

Our preference was to use a SQL service account.  We set the SQL server and SQL agent to run as a service account and then allowed the devs to trigger agent jobs.  The service account was granted permission to the UNC shares and this all functioned correctly.  Note that the service account will always been fine running these agent jobs (assuming UNC permissions are set).  It's the Devs trying to test that will come across these issues.

Another method is to create a share on the SQL server itself and point the bulk insert path at the local directory.  These errors seem to only occur when accessing UNC paths.  Regardless of whether the UNC path has the correct permissions to allow you access.  For example we create `C:\test\` as a folder on the SQL server itself and permission it to allow a dev to drop test files there.  These are then called via the bulk insert command.

A command may need to be run against master to allow a SQL login group permission to bulk insert.  This is as below.

```
GRANT ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS TO "domain\usergroup"
```

Answer (score 4):

Adam Saxton's blog (about Kerberos and bulk inserts from a share) should be read: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2012/09/07/bulk-insert-and-kerberos.aspx. Adam offers two approaches: 
Enable constrained delegation for the machine (as opposed to the sqlservr.exe startup) account, or use a SQL Server login. Adam mentions two other approaches (which he does not recommend).

An aside, the latter half of the OP's message "(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105)" may be related to a SQL Server startup account lacking rights documented within SQL Server's "Configure Windows Service Accounts and Permissions" topic, such as SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege.

Comment: The SQL Dude has a good write up on how to setup Kerberos to fix this issue.  https://thesqldude.com/2011/12/30/how-to-sql-server-bulk-insert-with-constrained-delegation-access-is-denied/

Comment: I think the better solution to generate (download) the file to the actual SQL box doing the import. This avoids the double hop issue. Plus the data doesn't have to go over network just to be read in for the insert.

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever resolve this issue? I recently had a similar problem and discovered that the best way to resolve it was to use a SQL login.

Initially, having read the notes [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175915.aspx) I thought if I just granted read permissions to the Windows account with which I was connecting to the SQL Server that would be okay, but even when I granted read access to `Everyone`, I still couldn't read in the file.

I believe the reason is something to do with SQL Server impersonating the windows user and attempting to access the UNC share, which is delegation and which is not allowed unless explicitly enabled. There are some notes [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998355.aspx) which may help. This is the constrained delegation of which you speak and *I couldn't get it to work either!*

**Bottom Line:** I just used a SQL Login and made sure the SQL Server Process account had read permissions on the share (by granting read to `Everyone` in my case) and it worked.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't remember exactly what was done, and I have changed jobs since June so it would be hard to track down. I gave up and let the local SQL admin guru have a look. IIRC, it was a case of granting permissions on the network share to the Windows account used to connect. When I checked, it appeared that permissions had already been granted. Something additional must have been done, though. Sorry.

Comment: I had the same issue. I granted the permission to the relevant account and it still didn't work. In the end I had to use a SQL login as I didn't want to spend hours and hours on something that didn't seem to work as advertised. I'm glad it's no longer a problem for you! ;-)

Comment: Hi, how to grant these permissions ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to bulk insert with AD users, the SQL service it self has to be running as a domain user and has to have the AD permission to be able to delegate authentication.  Same if you wanted to run linked servers with ad users.  Here is the link for AD and linked servers, but the permission are the same.

[Linked Servers and Active Directory](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms189580%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx)

- The server must have an SPN registered by the domain administrator.
- The account under which SQL Server is running must be trusted for delegation.
- The server must be using TCP/IP or named pipes network connectivity.