# Upload .csv to SQL server using C++

Tags: c++, sql, csv, upload, permissions

I am working with Visual Studio 2012 Express version under Windows 7. On the other hand, the SQL server is "SQL Server 2008 R2".

I've tried following C++ codes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqltypes.h>
#include <sqlext.h>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    clock_t start = clock();

    SQLHANDLE sqlevent, sqlconnection, sqlstatement;

    if(SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &sqlevent))       
    {
        cout<<"The sqlevent has failed to be created."<<endl;
        system("pause");
        return;
    }


    if(SQL_SUCCESS != SQLSetEnvAttr(sqlevent, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0))
    {
        cout<<"The sqlevent has failed to be initialized."<<endl;
        system("pause");
       return;
    }

    if(SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlevent, &sqlconnection))
    {
        cout<<"The sqlconnection has failed to be created."<<endl;
        system("pause");
        return;
    }

    SQLCHAR retstring[10000];
    SQLDriverConnect(sqlconnection, NULL, (SQLCHAR*)("DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};SERVER=DATASERVER;DATABASE=DATABASE;UID=CrystalReports;PWD=PASSWORD"), SQL_NTS, retstring, 10000, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);  

    if(SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlconnection, &sqlstatement))
    {
        cout<<"The sqlstatement has failed to be created."<<endl;
        system("pause");
        return;
    }

    string commandline;

    commandline = "CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE ( ID VARCHAR(10), AGE FLOAT) GO ";

    if(SQL_SUCCESS != SQLExecDirect(sqlstatement, (SQLCHAR*)(commandline.c_str()), SQL_NTS))
    {
        cout<<"The create table sql command has failed to excute."<<endl;
        system("pause");
        return;
    }

    commandline = "BULK INSERT NEW_TABLE FROM 'C:/temp/datafile.csv' WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n') GO";

    if(SQL_SUCCESS != SQLExecDirect(sqlstatement, (SQLCHAR*)(commandline.c_str()), SQL_NTS))
    {
        cout<<"The import sql command has failed to excute."<<endl;
        system("pause");
        return;
    }

    clock_t end = clock();

    cout<<"Import from .csv file to SQL Server costs "<<((end-start)/double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC))<<" seconds."<<endl;

    system("pause");

    return;

}
```

When I run this code, the program always stops at create table.

I wonder if I don't have the permission to create a table, thus I mannually created a table. And there is a warning pops out:

[image]

May I know if the warning shown in the above image is the reason my code fail, or I simply made mistakes in the code?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Who owns the database? You need to find your database administrator and get them to grant you permission to add tables to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check what permissions that account has been GRANTED.

You will need permissions to INSERT as well as to [BULKADMIN server role](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189934%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx).

But as you can see in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11230361/what-permissions-are-required-to-bulk-insert-in-sql-server-from-a-network-share) it can get hairy depending on where the file is located. You can at